# JavaScript browser related classes, objects & functions

Tags: javascript, qt, setinterval

I'm using Qt 5.4, & i'm trying to use the function setInterval() in javaScript

```
setInterval(function handleClick(xAxis , yAxis, ccc){

    if (ccc.checker === true){
        messageDialog.text = "X Value equals " + xAxis + " Y = " + yAxis;
        messageDialog.visible = true;        
    }

},3000);
```

but it's giving me an error saying ReferenceError: setInterval is not defined

Same thing happend to me when i tried to use the class fabric in JavaScript, So, the question is can these functions & classes be used outside browsers or they have been created to be used in web pages through browsers Only, & if so is there any libraries that i can import to use such classes & functions in my program using Qt.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about [QtScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QtScript) . In that case you should take in to account that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are not defined in ECMAScript specification because they are not JavaScript features. These functions are part of browser environments. Which means QtScript does not support them .

This is the way to do it :

```
var timer = new QTimer();
timer.interval = 3000;
timer.singleShot = false;
timer.timeout.connect(this, function handleClick(xAxis , yAxis, ccc){
    if (ccc.checker === true){
        messageDialog.text = "X Value equals " + xAxis + " Y = " + yAxis;
        messageDialog.visible = true;        
    }
});
timer.start();
```

I did not try loading third parity libraries, but my guess would be that most of them will fail to do so .

Comment: Thanks, but it gave me an error saying: ReferenceError: QTimer is not defined, So i have tried to import the class QTimer as follows: .import QTimer 2.2 as Timer, but that didn't workout, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: you should `#include <QTimer>` in your source file .

Comment: but what if i wanted to import it in JavaScript file not in C++, Is that possible ?